# Install drivers on another Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, ahci

I have a USB drive with an ISO from which I can install Windows 7, but it doesn't support AHCI drives. How can I add support for that capability to the ISO?

I've heard there is an option to install a driver for a Windows on another drive instead of the currently running system, but I don't know any details.

Comment: Instead of modifying the ISO you could simply load the required drivers before starting the actual installation: https://superuser.com/questions/609051/why-is-there-load-driver-during-windows-installation (the question is for Vista, but AFAIR driver loading was the same  with Windows 7). Note that Windows 7 is EOL, you should no longer install it. Instead just make a fresh Windows 10 installation and activate it using the Windows 7 key (still possible).

Comment: You would have to download the ISO, extract the ISO and modify the contents, then write those contents to the USB drive instead of the ISO. There are lots of articles on how to add a USB 3.0 driver to the Windows 7 ISO you can use that as a baseline

Comment: "but it doesn't support AHCI drives" do you mean it does not recognize the drive during installation, if so it may need a sata (or raid) driver. You need to add more details to your question on exactly what the problem is during installation.

Comment: Robert - Trying to extract the key and use it in fresh Win10 didn't work; it was the first thing I tried. The Win7 ISO I have already has a key in it, so I wanted to use that and update installed system to Win10.
Ramhound - Thanks, that's a good starting point. Sounds like it would work, just have to find the proper drivers.
Moab - My friend said the problem is with the drive being AHCI and the ISO being very old. The drive is a new M.2 NVMe.
I'm not able to write any resolution to this issue as I've already used an alternative and don't have any other M.2 drives or ports to test this on.

Comment: Your friend is wrong, but on the right track. If the drive is NVMe, then it's not AHCI, because NVMe is a modern replacement for AHCI. The ISO is certainly missing NVMe support though.

Answer (score -2):

Installing Windows from USB sometimes causes this issue. In most cases, when I installed from physical DVD-drive (also can be an USB DVD drive), the problem did not appear

This is a workaround, not a solution in this case

Comment: You're missing the point. The ISO doesn't contain drivers necessary to detect OP's drive. It doesn't matter if you burn it to a DVD or create a bootable USB - the drivers will still be missing in both cases.

Comment: "Installing Windows from USB sometimes causes this issue." - Except that isn't the author's problem.